# Can we trim the text stream [DT_TEXT] lnput column length to 1000 characters in SSIS before sending it to output column

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am new to SSIS so please bear with me.

I have a external column in my **SSIS** package with text stream `[DT_TEXT]` data type (**length 0**) the **output column** is string `[DT_STR]` (**length 1000**).

Is there a way to trim the length of external column text stream `[DT_TEXT]` to **1000** before sending to output.

Any help will be really appreciated.

I have tried **Advanced Editor** Column length column is disabled(as obvious) for text stream `[DT_TEXT]` data types.

Any input will be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try `Substring(txt,0,1000)`

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to take a look at using a [Data Conversion Transformation Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/data-conversion-transformation-editor):

> Use the Data Conversion Transformation Editor dialog box to select the columns to convert, select the data type to which the column is converted, and set conversion attributes.

You can set the input column, output alias, data type and length. This would then produce a new aliased column in the new type.

This link provides sample of how this can be achieved:

[SSIS Data Conversion](http://www.tutorialgateway.org/ssis-data-conversion/)

You can see how various input columns are being transformed, with an output Data Type and Length.

> [image]